# Show / hide on LocalStorage doesn't work correct, its all or nothing

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a script which saves an action on local storage.
My issue is when I refresh the page it show all items or none.
Not just the one which was clicked. (all items with class 'show-block' gets style="display:block".) So probably needs storage per item..

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wxhqr3t6/18/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".collapse").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
    localStorage.setItem("display", $(this).siblings().is(":visible"));
  });
  var block = localStorage.getItem("display");
  if (block == "true") {
    $(".show-block").show()
  }
});
```

Comment: Well... You neither store which item is visible or try to read such information. Are you asking us to write the rest of the code ?

Comment: Yes, because I don't know how to do it per item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a data-index property for each collapse class, and save localStorage with it. Follow my example:
With html:

```
After refresh its not possible to show just 1 or 2 items. Its show all or hide all.<br>

<article class="filter-transmission">
  <h2 class="filter-title collapse" data-index="1">Show content 1</h2>

  <div class="show-block">
    content 1 here!
  </div>
</article>

<article class="filter-transmission">
  <h2 class="filter-title collapse" data-index="2">Show content 2</h2>

  <div class="show-block">
    content 2 here!
  </div>
</article>

<article class="filter-transmission">
  <h2 class="filter-title collapse" data-index="3">Show content 3</h2>

  <div class="show-block">
    content 3 here!
  </div>
</article>

<input type="button" value="Refresh Page" onClick="window.location.reload()">
```

With javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( ".collapse" ).each(function() {
    var block = localStorage.getItem("display"+$(this).data("index"));
    if (block == "true") {
      $(this).closest("article").find(".show-block").show();
    }
  });
  $(".collapse").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
    localStorage.setItem("display"+$(this).data("index"), $(this).siblings().is(":visible"));
  });
  var block = localStorage.getItem("display"+$(this).data("index"));
  if (block == "true") {
    $(".show-block").show()
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track each item separately then you have to put unique IDs on each of them and store a JSON object (by using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`) in `localStorage`, e.g.

```
display = 
{
  id_1: false,
  id_2: true,
  id_3: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (localStorage.getItem('display') == null) {
    localStorage.setItem("display", JSON.stringify([]));
  }
    const elements = $('.filter-transmission');
  elements.find(".collapse").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
    const index = $(this).parent().index();
    let items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("display"));
    if (items.includes(index)) {
        items.splice(items.indexOf(index), 1);
    } else {
        items.push(index);
    }
    localStorage.setItem("display", JSON.stringify(items));
  });
  var openedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("display"));
  elements.each((el) => {
    if (openedItems.includes(el)) {
        console.log('el', el);
        $(elements).eq(el).find('.show-block').show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I like the script from protoproto even more